# Python: How to use functions inside numpy?

Tags: python, function, numpy, call

I am new to Python programming, so please bear with my nascent question.

If we want to use certain function inside numpy, say `func`, do we need to **just** import numpy once and then call the function as following:

```
import numpy
np.func
```

**Or, do we further need to import specific sub modules of numpy before calling any function?** Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `linalg` you have to do:

```
numpy.linalg
```

For example, if you want to calculate determinant of x, you would do

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([[1,2],[5,7]])
det_x = numpy.linalg.det(x)

#or

import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[5,7]])
det_x = np.linalg.det(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good source to learn about those submodules inside numpy and scipy?

Comment: I find manuals of type "Numpy for Matlab users" to be quite good, especially to get started. Even though I am hardly a matlab user, they have helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Almost, if you want to use `numpy` as `np` you have to import it like this:

```
import numpy as np
```

Other than that you can use the functions like that.

Comment: If I write `import numpy`, then I have to write `numpy.func`?

Answer (score 3):

As with *every other fricking module in existence*, you use the name you import it as.

```
import numpy
numpy.func
```

...

```
import numpy as np
np.func
```

Comment: To be fair, there are plenty of modules where a particular sub-module isn't included in the `__init__` for the main module. I'm guessing the OP's questions stems from `scipy`.  `scipy`'s `__init__` basically just imports `numpy`.  All of `scipy`'s functionality is in submodules that you have to explicitly import.

Comment: @Joe: You get what you import. That hasn't changed.

Comment: No, it hasn't, but if the OP is using `numpy`, they're probably using `scipy` as well.  It's common to be confused as to why there's so much code similar to `import scipy.ndimage` and why you can't just do `import scipy` and then access `scipy.ndimage`. Or maybe I'm just reading too much into the question.